# How to allow user to tweet their message on web view in android

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am able to post tweet simply in android, but i want to tweet it with help of WebView, Could you please it possible for me in which WebView will be rediret on main activity and user can edit message and tweet it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
public class TwitterScreen extends Activity {

    private Twitter twitter;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private WebView webView;
    private String twitterUrl;
    String twittMessage;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.twitter_xml);

        twittMessage = "This Is Android";
        twitterUrl = twitterConnection();
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        try {
            webView.loadUrl(twitterUrl);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new ContactUsWebViewClient());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sendTweetByApp(twittMessage);

    }

    public String twitterConnection() {

        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        RequestToken requestToken = null;
        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();

        System.out.println("twitter Url load" + url);
        System.out.println("UserName");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(TwitterScreen.this, "", "Loading...",
                true, true);
        Thread threadHandler = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        threadHandler.start();

        return url;
    }

    private class ContactUsWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void sendTweetByApp(String message) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/?status=" + Uri.encode(message)));
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

Comment: this is the complete class that u want to do (editing the msg in tweeting time in web view) don't forget to miss the twitter4j lib

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, but I am unable to do tweet by implement above class in my code. Can you please send me whole steps with relavent code , so that i can login in WebView after comeback on a WebView and edit Message for tweet.

Comment: As free from your busy schedule , my email id -  tikam.tailor@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Java library to implement Twitter OAuth with the help of your own WebView http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html